# Java quote.split to only 1 word

Tags: java, split

I'm creating a program in java which can do various things for you like open programs.
And I want to know if it's possible to use the .split function to only remember 1 word after the part that had to be split.

This is how it works now;

```
User: Can you open chrome? (this is where the program looks for the word 'open' and saves all that comes after it)
Program: Sure, I'll open chrome for you. (chrome opens)
```

Now, I want it to only remember the first word after the word 'open'.
Is this possible?
If so, what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You can first split your text based on a word delimiter (a space in your example). Afterwards, get the index of the word "open" in your array and take the value at `index + 1`. This is the word that comes right after your token of choice.

Comment: `"Some string".replaceAll("^.*open ", "").replaceAll("^(.*?\\b).*$, "$1");` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex to get the string after `open` is probably the most flexible way:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {


     String line = "Will you open chrome?";
     //will get everything after open, including punctuation like the question mark.
     //You need to modify the regex if that's not what you want.
     String pattern = "open (.*)";

     // Create a Pattern object
     Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

     // Now create matcher object.
     Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

     if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Value after open is: " + m.group(1));
     } else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
     }
  }
```

Returns: `Value after open is: chrome?`

If you don't want the question mark,  update the regex to exclude the question mark from the matching group:

```
String pattern = "open (.*)\\?";
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
String command=line.split("open\\s*\\b")[1];
```

You need to check for the index of the splitted string and so on, but this shall work.